# Having stack overflow reading a file into a 2D array code 3221225725

Tags: c, file-handling

I´m trying a code to read a csv file into a 2D array (from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gaq10GBlRJA)

The number of columns and rows I´m working with is 4096 (16 777 216 elements), and my code leads to abnormal termination showing "[Done] exited with code=3221225725 in 0.267 seconds"

I tried to import another matrix (100x100) and it runs perfectly. I´m wondering maybe 4096 is too big to handle.

This is the code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 4096
#define COLUMNS 4096

int main(void) {
  float array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

  FILE *file;

  file = fopen("Psi.csv", "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  int row = 0;

  while (!feof(file)) {
    if (ferror(file)) {
      printf("Error reading file.\n");
      return 1;
    }

      if (fscanf(file, "%f,", &array[row][i]) == EOF)
        break;
    }

    row++;

    if (row == ROWS)
      break;
  }
  fclose(file);

 
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
      printf("%.1f ", array[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It _may_ help to know the hexadecimal representation of the error code: dec `3221225725` = hex `C00000FD`: https://www.google.com/search?q=c00000fd+error+code

Comment: The size of `float array[ROWS][COLUMNS]` is over 60 Mbytes, which is most likely far too much for most implemantations. Usually local variables are stored on the stack and the typical standard stack size on Windows is 1Mb and on Linux it is 8Mb. There must be several duplicates of this question.

Comment: Unrelated, but still worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong